# Best way to handle phosphorus tribromide

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

I need to do an alcohol bromination using PBr3 and I've never done this reaction before. Reading about PBr3 I found it is water/air-sensitive and the bottle I bought doesn't have a seal. So how am I supposed to manipulate it if I can't expose it to air? Just open the bottle and insert an Ar flow rapidly? Is there a more refined procedure to deal with this without a glove-box? I tried reading procedures on papers but they usually just say "PBr3 was added to the flask", nothing else.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think it's *very* sensitive. More like too much contact with air decreases yield a few percent sensible, probably.

Comment: PBr3 is a high boiling liquid that can be measured gravimetrically or volumetrically in a vented hood.

Comment: Do you have a nitrogen gas supply?